# Jquery is selecting only the first option from select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {           
            $("[id*=btnSave]").bind("click", function () {
                debugger;               
                    var user = {};
                    user.Projectname = $('#select-comm-type').find("option:selected").text();
                    user.Emailid = $("[id*=Emailtext]").val();              
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "FrmTmsClient.aspx/SaveEmail",
                    data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("EmailId has been added successfully.");
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });         
                return false;
            });
        });

</script>
```

in user.Projectname takes only the 1st option from select with id=select-comm-type. I want other options from select.

Comment: Could you add the html to it. What I can tell you already, find searches for the first occurence. So if the first on is option:selected it will take this one every time.

Comment: Do you want to get value of selected option or want to get the option text of selected option?

Comment: even if i use  $('#select-comm-type').val(); , it is selecting the value of the first option only.

Comment: Yes i could add html to it. Doomenik can you explain more please.

Answer (score 0):

For Selected **Value** of

```
jQuery("#select-comm-type option:selected").val();
```

or

```
$("#select-comm-type option:selected").val();
```

and

For Selected **Text** of

```
jQuery("#select-comm-type option:selected").text();
```

or

```
$("#select-comm-type option:selected").text();
```

More Details:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

http://api.jquery.com/text/